# how to download a csv file for checked list in RShiny using checkBoxGroup

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a binger in Shiny app and I need help with my code.
I've created a list of checkboxes for group of items(choiceNames), and I want user to be able to download the value of the checked items(choiceValues) only as csv file.  How can i write the output code in this case?
[pic for the checked list in ShinyApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVGih.png)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel(h1(" Birth Worksheet",align="center")),
    hr(),

    sidebarPanel(  
        titlePanel(h4("Antenatal Risk Factors/Current Pregnancy",align="center")),
        hr(),
 checkboxGroupInput("Antel", "  ",
                     choiceNames =
                       list("Urinary tract infections this pregnancy",
                            "Urinary tract infections this pregnancy, treated",
                            "Anemia this pregnancy (HCT < 30/Hgb <10)",
                            "Hemoglobinopathy this pregnancy",
                            "Coagulation disorder",
                            "Rh sensitization",
                            "Other iso-immunization",
                            "Biliary/liver disorder(Yes at delivery)",
                            "Cardiac disease",
                            "Autoimmune disease",
                            "Antiphospholipid syndrome",
                            "Specify collagen vascular disease",
                            "Asthma",
                            "Acute or chronic lung disease",
                            "Renal disorder/disease",
                            "Renal dialysis or end stage renal disease",
                            "Thyroid disease",
                            "Cancer this pregnancy",
                            "Cancer treatment this pregnancy"
                       ),
                     choiceValues =list("RFC_INFUT","RFC_INFUTTX",
                                          "RFC_ANEMIA",
                                          "RFC_HEMO",
                                          "COAGULATION_DISORDER",
                                          "RFC_RHS",
                                          "RFC_ISO",
                                          "BILARY_LIVE_DISORD",
                                          "RFC_CDDZ",
                                          "RFC_CVDZ",
                                          "RFC_APSY",
                                          "RFC_CVSPEC",
                                          "RFC_ASTH",
                                          "RFC_LGDZ",
                                          "RENAL_DISORDER_DISEASE",
                                          "RFC_RNDY",
                                          "RFC_THYDZ",
                                          "RFC_CA",
                                          "CANCER_TREATMENT" )
  ),       
                    
       
)


server <- function(input, output) {

   
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `downloadButton` and a corresponding `downloadHandler`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(h1(" Birth Worksheet", align = "center")),
  hr(),
  sidebarPanel(
    titlePanel(h4("Antenatal Risk Factors/Current Pregnancy", align = "center")),
    hr(),
    checkboxGroupInput("Antel", "  ",
      choiceNames =
        list(
          "Urinary tract infections this pregnancy",
          "Urinary tract infections this pregnancy, treated",
          "Anemia this pregnancy (HCT < 30/Hgb <10)",
          "Hemoglobinopathy this pregnancy",
          "Coagulation disorder",
          "Rh sensitization",
          "Other iso-immunization",
          "Biliary/liver disorder(Yes at delivery)",
          "Cardiac disease",
          "Autoimmune disease",
          "Antiphospholipid syndrome",
          "Specify collagen vascular disease",
          "Asthma",
          "Acute or chronic lung disease",
          "Renal disorder/disease",
          "Renal dialysis or end stage renal disease",
          "Thyroid disease",
          "Cancer this pregnancy",
          "Cancer treatment this pregnancy"
        ),
      choiceValues = list(
        "RFC_INFUT", "RFC_INFUTTX",
        "RFC_ANEMIA",
        "RFC_HEMO",
        "COAGULATION_DISORDER",
        "RFC_RHS",
        "RFC_ISO",
        "BILARY_LIVE_DISORD",
        "RFC_CDDZ",
        "RFC_CVDZ",
        "RFC_APSY",
        "RFC_CVSPEC",
        "RFC_ASTH",
        "RFC_LGDZ",
        "RENAL_DISORDER_DISEASE",
        "RFC_RNDY",
        "RFC_THYDZ",
        "RFC_CA",
        "CANCER_TREATMENT"
      )
    ),
    downloadButton("download_checkboxes")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$download_checkboxes <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "checkboxes.csv"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      data <- data.frame(selected = input$Antel)
      write.csv(data, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thank you, that's work. is there a way to show the choicesNames and choiceValue together in the download csv file?

Comment: Yes. Set the column to the choices and then add a new column with ifelse.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get it. where I'm supposed to add the column? do you mind explain it with an example.